# Euler cycle, difference between loop and function

Tags: c

Could someone explain me what is the difference between a loop in euler() and the deleting function?

For me is it identical but somehow the programme only works with the function deleting.

```
#ifndef __HIERHOLZER_H__
#define __HIERHOLZER_H__

#include "stack.h"

/*int deleting(struct graph *g, int u, struct stack *stack){
    for(int v=0;v<g->size;v++){
        if(g->matrix[u][v]==1 && g->matrix[v][u]==1){
            g->matrix[u][v]=0;
            g->matrix[v][u]=0;
            stack_push(stack,v);
            u=v;
            return deleting(g,u,stack);
        }
    }
}*/

void euler(struct graph *g, int *cycle) {

     struct stack *stack = stack_create(g->edges);

     stack_push(stack,0);
     int u;
     int cycle_counter=0;

     while(!stack_is_empty(stack)){

        u=stack->elements[stack->index-1];

        for(int v=0;v<g->size;v++){
            if(g->matrix[u][v]==1 && g->matrix[v][u]==1){
            g->matrix[u][v]=0;
            g->matrix[v][u]=0;
            stack_push(stack,v);
            u=v;
            v=0;
            }
        }
        //deleting(g,u,stack);
        cycle[cycle_counter++]=stack_pop(stack);
     }

      stack_destroy(stack);
}

#endif
```

Comment: If a function is declared `void` you can't return a value from it.

Comment: The return statement will end the loop, so you only process part of the array in the `deleting()` function.

Comment: @Barmar, problem solved the loop in euler() works if v=-1 instead of v=0 at the end of the if().